# How to setup virtual env or install a python library when I try to submit a PySpark job to Databricks from Airflow?

Tags: pyspark, airflow, databricks, livy

I need to submit a PySpark job to Airflow through LivyOperator. I see there are arguments to the LivyOperator's init method where users can pass in a list of Python files, but is there a way to do this more cleanly? For example, what if I would like install some 3rd library? Is there a way I can setup a virtual environment? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

To run job on Databricks you need to use [Databricks-specific operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/operators/index.html). Specifically, look onto [DatabricksSubmitRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/operators/submit_run.html). This operator allows to specify tasks to execute, together with libraries that are required for these tasks.

P.S. it's really not enough information to put more detailed answer...